# Error when trying to install my new module in odoo14

Tags: python, xml, odoo-14

when trying to install my new app I'm  getting the fallowing error :

File "C:\odoo14\server\odoo\http.py", line 317, in _handle_exception
raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/c:/odoo14/server/odoo/addons/pfe/views/pfe.xml:9, near

```
        <field name="name">Patients</field>

        <field name="res_model">hospital.patient</field>

        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>

        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>

        <field name="help" type="html">

            <p clas="oe_view_nocontent_create">

                create your first patient!

            </p>

        </field>


    </record>
```

Comment: Please, send all code from view. There is an error typo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see an issue in your post xml in p tag the `class` attribute is not correct. You write it `clas`

```
 <p clas="oe_view_nocontent_create">
      create your first patient!
 </p>
```

it should be:

```
 <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
     create your first patient!
 </p>
```